# Executing a system command from mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, user-defined-functions, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to execute a shell command from within mysql (from within a procedure or a trigger or the command line for mysql).

I have added lib_mysqludf_sys to the mysql plugins and created the functions that are available with the library. (the library) [home page](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php)

The library has 5 functions.

1. sys_set - to set $PATH - this works and stores the $PATH which i can later check.
2. sys_get - to get the stored value of $PATH - this also works and returns the value that I have stored.
3. sys_exec - to execute a command in the system and return the exit code.
4. sys_eval - to execute a command in the system and return the standard output.
5. lib_mysqludf_sys_info - return the current version of the library -  this also works.

I need sys_exec and sys_eval to work correctly.

I think I have found the problem in my search but cannot solve it.

mysql is limited by [apparmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) and is not granted access to execute system commands by the default apparmor profile. I have tried the commands in the documentation to disable a single profile, disable the framework, putting all profiles except one into enforce mode and putting all profiles in complain mode. Nothing works. the command

```
sudo apparmor_status
```

always gives me the same output.

```
20 profiles are loaded.
20 profiles are in enforce mode.
  /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/unity-lens-askubuntu/unity-askubuntu-daemon
  /sbin/dhclient
  /usr/bin/evince
  /usr/bin/evince-previewer
  /usr/bin/evince-previewer//launchpad_integration
  /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
  /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
  /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper
  /usr/bin/evince//launchpad_integration
  /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
  /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
  /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
  /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
  /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper
  /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
  /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*
  /usr/sbin/cupsd
  /usr/sbin/mysqld
  /usr/sbin/tcpdump
  /usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession
0 profiles are in complain mode. 
5 processes have profiles defined. 
5 processes are in enforce mode.    
  /sbin/dhclient (2537)     
  /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 (2709)  
  /usr/sbin/cupsd (12245)     
  /usr/sbin/cupsd (12250)     
  /usr/sbin/mysqld (12675)  
0 processes are in complain mode. 
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Please tell me how I could disable apparmor or change the profile for mysql so that it has access to executing system commands.

The reason I am doing all this is so that I can execute a system command when somethings happen in the DB (via a DB trigger), if you have suggestion for some other ways in which this can be easily implemented then please mention those too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

managed to get this working. First put apparmor in complain mode for the necessary profiles then used apparmor's interactive tools (aa-genprof/aa-logprof) to configure the profile for mysqld