# How can I query CPU Utilization from MySQL running on RedHat?

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL 5.6 Community on RedHat 6 and am trying to find a way that I can query from within MySQL and get the current CPU Utilization % at that moment. I have looked through the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks,
--Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this UDF Lib you can execute every system command. So you can start what ever you want and get the result from them.

[Executing a system command from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376308/executing-a-system-command-from-mysql][1])